# Unwind segue doesn't work for iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1), but write it in Swift instead of Objective-C.

I've connected `Cancel and Save` button to `Exit` button in 
`AddToDoItemViewController` as unwind segue to function in `ToDoListTableViewController`.

```
    @IBAction func unwindToList(segue : UIStoryboardSegue){
        println("unwindToList")

    }
```

When I click `Cancel and Save`, the button on device or emulator function is not invoked and exit not triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Project download: http://www.filedropper.com/test_16
Mac OS: 10.10.3
XCode 6.3.2
Command line tools: 6.3
iOS Device: 8.3
Emulator: iPhone 6 (iOS 8.3)

I Also tried the same with Objective-C and got same issue.

Comment: do you have the action in the source view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded your project, and it appears the issue is a wrong custom class name given to the To-Do List table view controller.
In the storyboard, for To-Do List Scene, the table view controller custom class is set to "ToDoList". Replace it with "ToDoListTableViewController", the name for the right class, and the unwind works.